# Submit a form to more than one url

Tags: form-submit

How can I submit a form to more than one URL at the same click? Like the following (hypothetical):

```
<form action="url1" action="url2" method="post">
  ...
  <input type=submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: In what language are you planning to do this?

Comment: You'd better go with fake it in JavaScript to create to post, there is no such a thing for html form tag

Answer (score 1):

You can do a sequential submit.

Submit to the first URL, and create a hidden form with all the fields from the original form.

After processing the form, if needed, call the submit action through javascript to go to the second action.